# Duda con Bases de Datos y Relaciones Ternarias

Tags: base-de-datos

Por mas que leo libros o los pdf de la uni que no ayudan mucho, no logro formular una respuesta.. Para mi si son ambas equivalentes para modelar el problema..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te refieres a que para ti su funcionalidad es la misma?

Comment: yo veo como diferencia que a) genera 4 tablas (medico, consulta, atiende y paciente) y b) genera 3 tablas (medico, consulta y paciente). La cosa esta en que la tabla `atiende` tendria los ids de medico, consulta y paciente (en el caso a) y en el caso b) la consulta  tendria los indices de medico y paciente.

Answer (score 2):

## ¿Alguno representa los requisitos de almacenamiento de la BBDD?

Los cuadritos son entidades (tablas) y los rombos son relaciones. Por lo tanto, en ambos casos **el diseño de la base de datos es igual**. Como referencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fuente: [association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

O también:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fuente: [Loopback: HasManyThrough-relations](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/HasManyThrough-relations.html)

De modo que ambos diagramas son equivalentes **en base de datos**. Ambos modelan con tres entidades: `medico`, `paciente` y `consulta`.

En su nivel más básico

medico

```
id_medico | nombre       | especialidad
----------------------------------
 1        | Dr Seisdedos | Urología
 2        | Dr Espinilla | Dermatología
```

en realidad sólo le puse la especialidad porque me pareció divertido, puedes obviar ese campo.

paciente

```
 id_paciente | nombre    
-------------------------
 1           | Juan
 2           | María
```

consulta

```
 id_consulta | id_medico | id_paciente
 -------------------------------------
     1       |     1     |      1
     2       |     2     |      1
     3       |     2     |      2
     4       |     1     |      2
```

Para efectos de la base de datos, la consulta es una entidad donde consta que se juntaron un médico y un paciente en un instante del tiempo. Puede tener atributos extra como hora y fecha, lugar, importe pagado, duración, etc.

La tabla de consultas tiene una llave foránea en `id_medico` referenciando la tabla `medico`. Y tiene una llave foránea en `id_paciente` referenciando la tabla paciente. Entonces:

- consulta **belongsTo** medico (via id_medico)
- medico **hasMany** consulta (via id_medico)
- consulta **belongsTo** paciente (via id_paciente)
- paciente **hasMany** consulta (via id_paciente)

E incluso

- paciente **ManytoMany** medico (via la tabla consulta)

Para lo que importa:

En un diagrama de flujo, UML o lo que quieras, tú puedes decir que el proceso o la acción que conecta a las entidades o actores es semánticamente distinto. A la base de datos no le importa en lo más mínimo. Son llaves foráneas y relaciones hasOne, hasMany, belongsTo, manyToOne, oneToMany, ManyToMany etc etc.

## Indique si ambas son equivalentes para modelar este problema

Pensándolo bien, no son equivalentes. El diagrama A indica que toda consulta da lugar a una atención. Esto no es cierto, porque el médico puede no estar disponible, el paciente puede no presentarse o la consulta puede cancelarse.

Acá hay un poco de semántica involucrada. Si se considera que una consulta se agenda de antemano y puede no realizarse si no se da el proceso "atiende" la entidad consulta sigue existiendo, sólo que tiene un estado que indica que no se realizó.

La alternativa B es más fiel al modelo en BBDD, principalmente porque muestra explícitamente que no hay una relación directa entre médico y paciente como no sea a través de la entidad consulta.

También muestra que la consulta sólo tiene lugar si el médico la otorga y el paciente asiste. Sin embargo, el diagrama B no es una relación ternaria. Es una conversión de una ternaria en dos binarias.

Comment: entonces el primer modelo no definiría una tabla `atiende` que indicara los ids implicados? Si añadieramos al problema el guardar la fecha que un paciente ha sido atendido en una consulta, no sería más lógico el modelo con 4 ,tablas?

Comment: Del diagrama se entiende que los rombos son un proceso, no una entidad. La entidad consulta contiene la fecha de atención, el lugar y todo lo demás.

Comment: Aunque sean procesos, luego como acabe siendo el modelo permite o no ciertas condiciones. En el caso a), si atiende pasa a tabla, podemos confirmar que un paciente es atendido en una consulta por un medico. En el caso b) no podemos confirmarlo. Solo sabemos que el medico da consultas, y el paciente asiste a consultas. Pero puede dar el caso de un medico que de consultas PERO ese paciente no vaya a la consulta. en el caso A) se cumple esa condicion (en caso de modelar `atiende` como tabla)

Comment: `consulta` puede tener un campo `estado` que pueda indicar si está "agendada" "realizada" o "cancelada". También puedes modelarlo con 5 tablas como dices tú, quitando el médico y el paciente de la entidad `consulta` y creando dos tablas de relación `otorga` con campos `(id_medico, id_consulta)` y `acude` con campos `(id_paciente, id_consulta)`, o bien 4 tablas en donde la entidad `atiende` contiene `(id_medico, id_paciente, id_consulta)`. Pero en ambos casos tendrás consultas huérfanas y no podrás consultar a qué se relacionan antes de que se efectúen

Comment: Creo que debí empezar preguntando: esos esquemas deben leerse como UML, BPMN, Flowchart o qué?

Comment: jajaja. yo también tenia que haberlo preguntado :). Pero vamos esta claro que podemos modelarlo de varias maneras... Por mi parte zanjo la discusión aqui, aunque es muy interesante (creo que sino podemos estar aquí delirando mucho tiempo)

Comment: Creo que estamos hablando de un modelo Entidad-Relación,  y en ese caso... mirándolo bien el diagrama A implica una falacia. El modelo en base de datos es el mismo, pero el A habría que cambiarlo considerando que `[paciente <--- atiende ---> médico]` es una entidad compuesta que tiene una relación intermedia con `consulta`.

Comment: Incluso podemos comentar que una entidad medico puede ser también un paciente, agrupamos estas dos entidades como usuarios y a su vez podrán tener atributos que indiquen si es un medico o un paciente o ambas en otra entidad (tabla).

Answer (score 0):

Tener en cuenta que el modelo entidad-relación, es parte de un proceso y no, un resultado final (es parte del primer paso para modelar una base de datos), entonces, los diagramas A y B muestran una representación del objecto de estudio (mundo real), al ser diferentes no tienen la misma interpretación.

La semántica del diagrama A, establece la participación de las tres entidades para que exista la relación.

La semantica del diagrama B, permite que exista una relación entre Consulta y Médico, aunque no exista una relación entre Consulta y Paciente.

¿tiene sentido que exista una consulta sin paciente? o ¿sin médico?

Si ambos diagramas se convierten a tablas y después a una aplicación, seguro que en ambos podrás almacenar la informacián, pero las reglas de insersión, actualización y eliminación, no serán las mismas.

Answer (score 0):

Depende de las cardinalidades. En el diagrama B puedes tener asociado a una consulta varios médicos (N>1) y a la misma consulta varios pacientes (M>1). Si es así no sabrías en una consulta qué médico atendió a cada paciente. Si a cada consulta solo puede estar asociado un médico a lo sumo (N=1) y un paciente a lo sumo (M=1) entonces lo que ocurre en B es que puedes repetir en una consulta diferente el mismo paciente y el mismo médico.

Se puede obligar a que toda consulta tenga médico asociado y paciente asociado sin más que imponer una cardinalidad mínima en la parte de médico de la relación otorga y en la parte de paciente en la relación acude. En A, sin embargo, en atiende eliges un elemento de cada entidad para formar ternas y una consulta podría estar asociada a distintos pares de médico paciente.

Esto tiene sentido si la consulta fuese un evento previo al que acuden pares médico-pacientes diversos, de forma que un mismo par médico-paciente puede acudir a diversas consultas, a una consulta un médico pueden acudir diversos pacientes y a una consulta un paciente le pueden atender diversos médicos. Lo de "diversos" si la cardinalidad máxima es n, si no sería solo 1 (un médico, un paciente, una consulta respectivamente).